# Xcode: No plugin registered to launch the process type widgetExtension

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm a code hobbyist, not familiar with SwiftUI at all. Trying to create a day countdown app for both iOS and macOS with SwiftUI. I'm using Xcode 14.3.

I want to make my app so that every event in the app would look like a small, configurable widget in the app, which the user can click into and edit. But I can never preview things in a widget context or preview the widgets themselves without using Simulator...

## App Structure

[App Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGmZ0.png)
All the files are auto generated by Xcode (I did not edit them at all, and that mean the ContentView has nothing to do with the rest of my app). All the files except `CountWidgetView`.

## CountWidgetView

Target Membership: Propedium (App)

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit

struct CountWidgetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}

struct CountWidgetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CountWidgetView()
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

Preview Error: Could not find a host (app, extension, framework) given the open files and active 'PreviewProvider' types. Make sure the open files and 'PreviewProvider' types are targets in the active scheme.

I don't understand why the [WWDC20 widget](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/building_widgets_using_widgetkit_and_swiftui) previewed just fine while mine doesn't work.

## PropediumWidgetMacOS

Target Membership: PropediumWidgetMacOSExtension

```swift
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent())
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration)
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration)             entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
}

struct PropediumWidgetMacOSEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Text(entry.date, style: .time)
    }
}

@main
struct PropediumWidgetMacOS: Widget {
    let kind: String = "PropediumWidgetMacOS"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            PropediumWidgetMacOSEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}

struct PropediumWidgetMacOS_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PropediumWidgetMacOSEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

Preview Error: No plugin registered to launch the process type widgetExtension.

## What I've Tried

I tried asking ChatGPT. It told me to link the `Intent.framework` to my `PropediumWidgetMacOSExtension`, but that didn't work. I've also messed around with my target memberships (the working of which I have no idea about), checking the Propedium (App) in `PropediumWidgetMacOSExtension`'s target membership and getting rid of `@main`, etc.

I also asked Perplexity.ai but the answer was even more far-off than GPT, so...

## The Plea

Can anybody tell me how I can fix this, or any alternative ways by which I can accomplish

> ...every event in the app would look like a small, configurable widget in the app, which the user can click into and edit.

Comment: ChatGPT will often give you believable lies, you really shouldn’t use it if you’re not already an expert and can discern them. Are you using the widget Xcode template?

Comment: Right...Yes all these files are Xcode templates unless otherwise stated.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez (forgot to @ )